# On iterator and I value in C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

My question is what is the reason that snippet A runs well but snippet B fails?

---

Snippet A

```
std::vector<double> a;
std::vector<double>::const_iterator i;
a.push_back(1);
a.push_back(2);
a.push_back(3);
a.push_back(4);
a.push_back(5);
for(i=a.begin(); i!=a.end(); ++i){
    std::cout<<(*i)<<std::endl;}
```

Snippet B

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(999);
int j = *(--v.end()); //What's wrong here?
```

Comment: In what way does Snippet B fail you?

Comment: You can't do that to a rvalue. It's just as nonsensical to decrement rvalue iterator as it is to do `--2`

Comment: http://ideone.com/dSjhtJ I don't see anything "not working"

Comment: You can use `*(v.end()-1)`, but you can't modify the `end()` iterator. It's like trying to do `--sizeof(array)`.

Comment: @Barmar, please post your answer as a solution so it can be accepted by Nicholas

Comment: @krzaq  why does it work on my compiler? im using gcc 4.9.2

Comment: @Barmar why does it work on my compiler? im using gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Yeah, now I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You can't so much as look at what the `iterator` refers to without UB, but I can't think of a good reason why you shouldn't be able to increment or decrement the returned `iterator` itself till you're blue in the face.

Comment: See **Element access** section in [this](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm)@user4581301

Answer (score 1):

Iterators are not required to support increment and decrement on rvalues. Pointers, in particular, don't. And a `vector`'s iterator may - but doesn't have to be - a pointer.

Therefore, `*--v.end()` is not required to work. Use `a.back()` instead (or `std::prev(v.end())` for the iterator).